# Se puede abrir una web en modo pantalla maxima? Creo que se llama modo kiosk

Tags: html

Estoy intentando que una de mis webs, al abrirla, que se abra en el modo kiosk (creo que se llama) sin las pestañas ni la barra de tareas.

Lo que probé es poner la URL en un `.bat`

Ejemplo:

```
start chrome.exe --kiosk http://prueba.com
```

Y lo abre perfecto como me gustaría, pero atreves de un `.bat`. Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin el `.bat`?

***EDIT***

He encontrado este código, lo cual lo aplique a mi web, pero funciona mediante un botón, alguna idea de como hacerlo automático, una vez que se abra la web?

código:

```
function GoInFullscreen(element) {
if(element.requestFullscreen)
    element.requestFullscreen();
else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen)
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen)
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
else if(element.msRequestFullscreen)
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
}

function GoOutFullscreen() {
if(document.exitFullscreen)
    document.exitFullscreen();
else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen)
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen)
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
else if(document.msExitFullscreen)
    document.msExitFullscreen();
}

function IsFullScreenCurrently() {
var full_screen_element = document.fullscreenElement || 
document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || 
document.msFullscreenElement || null;


if(full_screen_element === null)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}

$("#go-button").on('click', function() {
if(IsFullScreenCurrently())
    GoOutFullscreen();
else
    GoInFullscreen($("#element").get(0));
});

$(document).on('fullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange 
mozfullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange', function() {
if(IsFullScreenCurrently()) {
    $("#go-button").text('Exit Full Screen');
}
else {
    $("#go-button").text('Full Screen');
}
});
```

En `HTML` tengo un `div` que agarra todo el contenido.

Comment: que seria por intermedio de quien? alguien debe ejecutar el chrome y decirle que se abra asi....

Comment: En tu aplicación la página de inicio debe hacer un re-open con Windows.open y utilizar los parámetros fullscreen=yes,menubar=no,toolbar=no,location=no

Comment: La web quiero que se abra de ese modo, se inicia con un usuario. Pero la idea es hacerlo automático, ya que dudo que el usuario final apriete F11 para maximizar la pantalla. Entonces una vez inicie con su usuario, esa web, se abra maximizada, no se si se entiende?

Comment: aclaro esa sección de la web pasan los "turnos", por eso, lo de que sea automático el maximizarlo, para que no moleste nada.  Estoy investigando, pero ninguno me resulta. :/

Comment: Interesante pregunta. Si agregas el código con el que has intentado le doy mi voto. Leyendo someramente encontré la [API Fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) pero no puedo probar en este momento. Intenta y nos cuentas si logras avanzar.

Comment: E agregado un EDIT